# How to add line number prefix to multi-line variable in shell scripting?

Tags: shell, unix, sh

I want to display a numbered menu from a shell script (#!/bin/sh).  Currently I use

```
echo "choice1
choice2
choice3
choice4
"
```

To output the menu.  Now I want to add a number prefix to each line so the result will look like:

```
1) choice1
2) choice2
3) choice3
4) choice4
...
```

How can I do this without having to manually prefix each line with a number?  I'm thinking I want to iterate over the variable line by line and concatenate the line number and output it to a new variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using `bash`, I'd recommend using the `select` built-in for these kind of tasks.

Here are [some examples](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_09_06.html).

Answer (score 2):

`select` is probably the way to go, but you could also do:

```
echo "$string" | nl -ba -s') '
```